# SQL Recursive CTE replace statement too slow

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a recursive CTE that replaces multiple values from an expression, but it is too slow when there are many expressions.

```
CREATE TABLE #table1(IdExpresion INT, expresion VARCHAR(MAX))
CREATE TABLE #table2(IdExpresion INT, searchExpresion VARCHAR(50), replacementExpresion VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO #table1(IdExpresion, expresion)
VALUES(1, 'Mary had a little lamb'),
      (2, 'The new student, student_name has the following grades Math - math_grade, Science - Science_grade')

INSERT INTO #table2(IdExpresion, searchExpresion, replacementExpresion)
VALUES(1, 'lamb','dog'),
      (2, 'student_name','Joe Smith'),
      (2, 'math_grade','A'),
      (2, 'Science_grade','B+')

;WITH cte(IdExpresion, expresion, lvl) AS
(
    SELECT t1.IdExpresion, t1.expresion, 1
    FROM #table1 t1
    UNION ALL    
    SELECT cte.IdExpresion, REPLACE(cte.expresion, t2.searchExpresion, t2.replacementExpresion), cte.lvl + 1 
    FROM cte  
    INNER JOIN #table2 t2
    ON cte.IdExpresion = t2.IdExpresion
       AND CHARINDEX(t2.searchExpresion, cte.expresion) > 0
)
SELECT DISTINCT c2.expresion
FROM (SELECT IdExpresion, MAX(lvl) AS lvl
      FROM cte
      GROUP BY IdExpresion) c1
INNER JOIN cte c2
   ON c1.IdExpresion = c2.IdExpresion 
      AND c1.lvl = c2.lvl
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Anyone have any advice? I am using SQL Server by the way

Comment: You may be able to get rid of `AND CHARINDEX(t2.searchExpresion, cte.expresion) > 0`. Depending on how many rows you have in `#table1`, the filter may add more overhead than just running the `REPLACE()` without it. Also, it might be more performant with a `cte.expression LIKE '%' + t2.searchExpress + '%'`.

Comment: What version of Sql Server

Comment: SQL Server 2016

Comment: Fast? See solution 1 in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35131098/243373).

Answer (score 1):

You could add another CTE to it that gets a row_number for each replacement, partitioned by the IdExpresion.

Then in the recursive CTE, instead of counting up, count down till there's no match with the replacement row_number.

The last entry in the CTE, that had all replacements, will have Lvl 0 then.

```
;WITH SEARCH AS (
  SELECT 
    IdExpresion, 
    row_number() over (partition by IdExpresion order by searchExpresion) as rn,
    searchExpresion, replacementExpresion
  FROM #table2
), CTE(IdExpresion, expresion, lvl) AS
(
    SELECT t1.IdExpresion, t1.expresion, count(*)
    FROM #table1 t1
    JOIN #table2 t2 ON t2.IdExpresion = t1.IdExpresion
    GROUP BY t1.IdExpresion, t1.expresion

    UNION ALL

    SELECT c.IdExpresion, REPLACE(c.expresion, s.searchExpresion, s.replacementExpresion), c.lvl - 1
    FROM CTE c
    JOIN SEARCH s
    ON s.IdExpresion = c.IdExpresion AND s.rn = c.lvl
)
SELECT IdExpresion, expresion
FROM CTE
WHERE lvl = 0
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

This way, each REPLACE is only done once per IdExpresion.
And that without having to use CHARINDEX.

You could also replace that SEARCH cte with a temporary table.
One that has the records from #table2 with that row_number.
This has the benefit that with a table you can add a compound index.
On a large table it should speed up the recursive join to the replacements.

Test on rextester [here](http://rextester.com/UPV1911)

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpSearch (
    IdExpresion INT, 
    rn INT,
    searchExpresion VARCHAR(50), 
    replacementExpresion VARCHAR(50),
    primary key (IdExpresion, rn));

insert into #tmpSearch (IdExpresion, rn, searchExpresion, replacementExpresion)
select 
 IdExpresion,
 row_number() over (partition by IdExpresion order by searchExpresion) as rn,
 searchExpresion, 
 replacementExpresion 
from #table2 
order by IdExpresion, searchExpresion;

;WITH CTE(IdExpresion, expresion, lvl) AS
(
    SELECT t1.IdExpresion, t1.expresion, max(s.rn)
    FROM #table1 t1
    JOIN #tmpSearch s ON s.IdExpresion = t1.IdExpresion
    GROUP BY t1.IdExpresion, t1.expresion

    UNION ALL

    SELECT c.IdExpresion, REPLACE(c.expresion, s.searchExpresion, s.replacementExpresion), c.lvl - 1
    FROM CTE c
    JOIN #tmpSearch s
    ON s.IdExpresion = c.IdExpresion AND s.rn = c.lvl
)
SELECT IdExpresion, expresion
FROM CTE
WHERE lvl = 0
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Comment: Nice idea, but there is no reason to use any loop for this request. Let me add another solution which I am guessing will be much better in performance...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if any more performant, but here is a brute force approach **just for fun**.

Already +1 LukStorm's answer, I suspect that is the way to go.

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(max) = (Select IdExpresion,expresion = replace(' '+expresion,' ',concat(' ',IdExpresion,'|||')) From #Table1 For XML Raw )

Select @S = replace(@S,concat(IdExpresion,'|||',searchExpresion),replacementExpresion) From  #table2

Select IdExpresion = B.i.value('@IdExpresion', 'int')
      ,expresion   = ltrim(replace(B.i.value('@expresion', 'varchar(max)'),B.i.value('@IdExpresion', 'varchar(25)')+'|||',''))
 From  (Select x = Cast(@S as xml).query('.')) as A 
 Cross Apply x.nodes('row') AS B(i)
```

**Returns**

```
IdExpresion expresion
1           Mary had a little dog
2           The new student, Joe Smith has the following grades Math - A, Science - B+
```

Comment: +1 Brute force can be fun. So you basically put everything in a varchar(max), replace everything in that string and then via a cast to XML transform back into a table.  Well, a varchar(max) can contain 2GB I think. So I guess it would have to be a fairly big #table1 to reach the limit.

Answer (score 0):

Good day,

Here is another solution. Please check if this fit your needs. This solution does not use any loop but simple dynamic query.

```
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(MAX);
-- do not make mistake, this is simple CTE and not a recursive CTE (no Loop)
;With MyCTE as (
    select R
    From table1 t1
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT R = 'SELECT ' + CONVERT (NVARCHAR(MAX),t1.IdExpresion) + ' as IdExpresion,' + STRING_AGG ('REPLACE','(') + '(' + 't1.expresion,''' + STRING_AGG(t2.searchExpresion + ''',''' + t2.replacementExpresion , '''),''') + ''') as expresion FROM table1 t1 where t1.IdExpresion = ' + CONVERT (NVARCHAR(MAX),t1.IdExpresion)
        from table2 t2
        where t2.IdExpresion = t1.IdExpresion
    ) C
)
SELECT @SQLString = STRING_AGG(R,'
UNION ALL
')
FROM MyCTE
--PRINT @SQLString
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString
GO
```

> **Note!** I recommend to execute some tests to confirm that this solves all cases
>
> **Note!** I am using the function `STRING_AGG` which was added to SQL Server 2017. In older version you can get the exact same solution using `FOR XML` statement.

Since we don't have the real DDL+DML we cannot really discuss about performance, but the difference in the execution plans of the solutions is 10% to 90% (In general, You should check IO and Time statistics in production in addition, before choosing your solution)

So... here is the Execution Plans Image (above query is my dynamic SQL solution and bellow is LukStorms solution using recursive CTE = Loop)

[image]

Comment: **Not!** I could not compare all 3 solutions, since the combine execution plans show zero percentage 0% for the solutions using Recursive CTE or Dynamic SQL while the XML Parsing show 100%. Therefore, I compared only the 2 queries that show better performance according to the EP