# Replacing same character multiple times with different replacement column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace

I have been scratching my head of how to do this with SQL server `REPLACE` or `STUFF` with `SUBSTRING`, `CONCAT` eg. without final resolution how to do it.

I have example a string:

```
'Product # has not been created for company # with language #'
```

What I would need to do is change each `'#'` with different result from different columns:

- First `'#'` should be replaced from Column `Data1` with content `'P0001'`
- Second `'#'` from column `Data2` with content `'1000'`
- Third `'#'` from column `Data3` with content `'EN'`

So end result should look like something like this:

```
'Product P0001 has not been created for company 1000 with language EN'
```

Comment: Do you always have the same number of `#`in your values?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: `STUFF(TemplateCol, CHARINDEX('#', TemplateCol), LEN('#'), Data1)` works for first column.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: If I had the choice to change the setup, I would either number the inserts (#1, #2, ...) or better yet, name them (#product_number#, #company_number# and #language_id#). That would make your problem somewhat easier and probably faster to solve. If you would opt for the last method, there's a solution I wrote for that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35131098/243373).

Answer (score 2):

One option is to split the string on the # and then simply reconstruct it

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(max) = 'Product # has not been created for company # with language #'

Select concat(
              xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')
             ,'P0001'
             ,xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')
             ,'1000'
             ,xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')
             ,'EN'
             ,xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')  
             )
 From ( values ( cast('<x>'+ replace( (Select replace(@S,'#','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§', '</x><x>') + '</x>' as xml ))) as A(xDim)
```

**Returns**

```
NewValue
Product P0001 has not been created for company 1000 with language EN
```

Answer (score 1):

With a [recursive CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
create table tablename(data varchar(max), data1 varchar(100), data2 varchar(100), data3 varchar(100));
insert into tablename(data, data1, data2, data3) values
('Product # has not been created for company # with language #', 'P0001', '1000', 'EN'),
('First # second # third # end', '1st', '2nd', '3d'),
('# a # b # c', '1', '2', '3');

with 
  cte as (
    select 2 id, data1, data2, data3, 
      case 
        when charindex('#', data) = 0 then data
        else left(data, charindex('#', data) - 1) +
             data1 +
             substring(data, charindex('#', data) + 1, len(data))
      end data  
    from tablename
    union all
    select id + 1, data1, data2, data3, 
      case 
        when charindex('#', data) = 0 then data
        else left(data, charindex('#', data) - 1) + 
             choose(id, data1, data2, data3) +              
             substring(data, charindex('#', data) + 1, len(data)) 
      end
    from cte
    where charindex('#', data) > 0
  )
select data 
from cte 
where charindex('#', data) = 0
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4e432adc69e2261c149ad437ae15b248).
Results:

```
> | data                                                                 |
> | :------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | 1 a 2 b 3 c                                                          |
> | First 1st second 2nd third 3d end                                    |
> | Product P0001 has not been created for company 1000 with language EN |
```

Comment: I was able to recreate string with Recursive CTE so thanks @forpas. 
As a information to anyone else looking for a solution, atleast I needed to add convert(varchar(max) to data in the primary and recursive CTE and followed table as I got the error

- Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "START" of recursive query "cte".

Comment: @Ar-Chi this is why I used `data varchar(max)` for the main column. This way you don't have to convert.